# Некоторые jquery плагины работают только в IE Edge, в остальных версиях нет

Tags: jquery, вёрстка, internet-explorer

При этом работает параллакс который тоже на *jquery*, *owlcarousel* и *typed.js*. Так же работаю ховер анимации написанные на *jquery*. Не работают *viewportChecker*, *countTo* и некоторые кастомные скрипты.

```
$(".facts").viewportChecker({
    callbackFunction: function() {
        $(".fact-to").countTo({
            speed: 500,
            refreshInterval: 2,
        });
    }
});
```